# Animate on changing the value of an observable in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I want to add animation when working with `observable` not `observableArray` which is already available in knockout documents.

Consider a `<div data-bind="text: fullname"/>` which `fullname` is an `observable`. I want the content of `<div>` element animate and slides down when the value of `fullname` changes. Something like:

```
<div data-bind="text: fullname, transition: slideDown"/>
```

Also, I'm using `Durandal` if it helps.

**Question:** How can I assign transition animations to observables?

Comment: Knockout's documentation has an example of how to implement animations: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html

Comment: @awj Yes I checked it as I said in the question. The problem is that it is only usable for `observableArray` not `observable`.

Answer (score 2):

The beforeRemove and afterAdd are just wrappers around the subscribe function.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['transition'] = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    var transition = valueAccessor(),
        target = allBindings.get('text'),
        subscriptions = [ 
          target.subscribe(target, onChange),
          target.subscribe(target, onBeforeChange, 'beforeChange')
        ];

    function onChange() {
      // handle transition when target updates
    }

    function onBeforeChange() {
      // handle transition BEFORE target updates
    }

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      subscription[0].dispose();
      subscription[1].dispose();
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I think it should be `target.subscribe(onChange),` instead of `target.subscribe(target, onChange),`. onBeforeChange's line as well. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) which does the animation for you:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.textSlide = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).text(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        if (value != $(element).text()) {
            $(element).slideUp(function() {
                $(this).text(value).slideDown();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ro0u9Lmb/